# Outlook Web Add-in Button Not Appearing in Ribbon

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins

I have developed an [Outlook Web Add-in](https://gist.github.com/zmicev/c2646f848e7a9ab8884b0ecabf92b183), but I am facing an issue.
After installing the add-in following the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/sideload-outlook-add-ins-for-testing?tabs=windows), the button I created does not appear in the Outlook Web ribbon.

The button is only visible when I select an email.
Could someone please guide me on what steps I might be missing or what configurations are needed to ensure that the button appears in the ribbon consistently, even when not selecting an email?